# What is the topology where all the direct distances are equal to $d_1$ and all the cross distances are equal to $d_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

What is the topology (2D or 3D representation) that corresponds to the following description:

We have $K$ pairs of points, where pair $k$ is denoted as $(P_k,Q_k)$.
We suppose that the distance between $P_k$ and $Q_k$ is the same (denoted by $d_1$) $\forall k= 1,...,K$. In addition, we assume that the distance between $P_k$ and $Q_i$ is the same (denoted by $d_2$)  $\forall k,i$ with $i \ne k$.
In other words, all the direct distances are equal to $d_1$ and all the cross distances are equal to $d_2$.

Note that $d_1 > d_2$.

PS: Any suggestion about an additional tag is welcome!

Comment: You basically described the distance in your post. Just take $d_1 < 2d_2$ to have a distance, then you're ok. But talking about "2D" or "3D" has no sense in this context

Comment: my question is how to represent these points (in 2D or 3D) based on the description..

Comment: It's not clear. There is no such set of points for the euclidian norm if K is big enough

Comment: We can suppose $K=10$.

Comment: In dimension 2, let's take the first pair (A,B), then all other points are in the intersection of the two circles of radius $d_2$ and center A and B : there is only two such points. This means that K is at most 2